# Passing awk output via bash variable to find

Tags: bash, awk, escaping, find, quotes

I wanted to get lists of "leaf" directory's that contain files but only if anyone of those directory's do not contain files changed within two time ranges.
I thought a bash script would be quick.. I found this: https://superuser.com/questions/195879/using-find-to-list-only-directories-with-no-more-childs
Now I have this:

```
#!/bin/bash
#get list of deepest directory's with files
#format output so directory's can contain spaces
check_dirs=$( { find . -type d ! -empty ; echo; } |
    awk 'index($0,prev"/")!=1 && NR!=1 {printf("\"%s\" ",prev);}
    {sub(/\/$/,""); prev=$0}' )
#run find once but get two lists of files to bash arrays --todo  
find ${check_dirs} \( -ctime 3 -print \), \( -ctime 8 -print \)
```

find handles the list of space separated quoted paths with spaces when run manually
but when run in a script it breaks on spaces and adds single quotes?
I get this kind of output:

> find: `"/path/to/suff"': No such file or directory
>
> find: `"/path/to/suff1"': No such file or directory
>
> find: `"/path/to/suffwith"': No such file or directory
>
> find: `"space"': No such file or directory
>
> find: `"in"': No such file or directory
>
> find: `"name"': No such file or directory
>
> find: `"/path/to/suff2"': No such file or directory

What's happening here?

Comment: You can try to escape the spaces in the names by changing `{sub(/\/$/,""); prev=$0}` in your `awk` expression to `{sub(/\/$/,""); (gsub(/ /,"\\ "); prev=$0}`.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the paths found have spaces in them, as you know. The problem is the line here:

```
find ${check_dirs} \( -ctime 3 -print \), \( -ctime 8 -print \)
```

Here, you allow wordsplitting on `$check_dirs`, and find isn't getting valid arguments from it, so it doesn't know how to proceed.

When you use quotes in the interactive shell bash uses the quotes to prevent wordsplitting, but when the quotes are inside a parameter bash performs wordsplitting *after* expanding the parameter, so the quotes are just part of the words.

The first step is composing a find command that "just" outputs leaf directories without any fuss. Here's one

```
find . -depth -type d -execdir bash -O dotglob -c 'set -- "$1"/*/; ! test -d "$1"' _ {} \; -print
```

Of course, instead of `-print` you could just combine your ctime predicates right after the \;.

Comment: I have little clue as to why interactive find "/folder/folder with space/" "/folder/folder" works but the script fails. whats the difference? any suggestion to handle it?

Comment: The find command you suggest would provide the "leaf" dirs but adding the ctime would apply to those same dirs? - Can I return a list of leaf dirs that don't contain files with a ctime of x in one go? If you respond I also am unsure what the _ does in your suggestion, could you explain it?

Comment: @user2844948 Yes, the way `find` works is the following predicates only apply to the files whose previous predicates were "true". I can explain the underscore, but not very easily in a comment. Suffice it to say that positional parameters start with 1, but counting starts with 0.

Answer (score 0):

You could look for files first, get their directory name, sort the list, get unique values and do something with the final list.

```
find . -newermt '2013-10-04 10:00:01' -not -newermt '2013-10-04 10:04:01' -print0 | \
xargs -r0 dirname | sort | uniq # <do something with your list>
```